# Show that two linear combinations of i.i.d. normal random variables are independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let $\{ \vec{v}_1, \ldots, \vec{v}_n \}$ form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let 
$$
\vec{X} = \begin{pmatrix} X_1 \\ \vdots \\ X_n \end{pmatrix}
$$
be a vector where each $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Let $Y_i = \vec{X}^t v_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$. How could we show that the $Y_i$'s are independent of each other?

Is it necessary to create a joint density function of each $Y_i,Y_j$ pair or is there an easier way since each $Y_i$ is simply a linear combination of $n$ random variables with standard normal distributions?

Comment: Hint: Let $U$ denote the matrix with rows $v_i$, so $U^t=U^{-1}$ and $Y = UX$. Let $cov$ denote the covariance matrix. Then $cov(Y) = cov(UX) = U (cov X) U^t = U I_n U^t = UU^t = I_n$, so $Y$ is multivariate normal with a diagonal covariance matrix. What can we say about that?

Comment: @Shalop, well in the case of your vector $Y$ with a multivariate normal distribution, we may use the property that any two elements that are uncorrelated are independent, hence the desired conclusion since your covariance matrix is diagonal. Is this your thinking as well?

Comment: Crucially missing is the hypothesis that the random variables $X_i$ are independent.

Comment: @mathjacks: yes that is my thinking.

Comment: @Did: Yes, but the title of the problem mentions the term "i.i.d" hence I assumed the $X_i$ to be independent.